# Multithreaded gdb - Tracking Variable Changes Before Crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I'm struggling to debug a multithreaded c++ program that I am working on. It seems to be crashing at the same spot in the code, but only some of the time due to a variable being deallocated by a different thread, causing the program to crash when the variable is accessed by a pointer after that.

Because of this, there is no way for me to step through the program for debugging. Is there any way to track all instances of a specific variable in gdb, and track what specific actions are performed to that memory location (so I can see who deallocated it, and where)? Or are there any other good ways to debug this?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm struggling to debug a multithreaded c++ program that I am working on

Debugging multithreaded programs with GDB (or any other debugger) *is* hard.

For the specific example you gave: one thread `free()`ing memory that another thread is still accessing, [Valgind](http://valgrind.org) and [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) will likely yield much better result than GDB.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll take a look at the two tools you linked to. I'm definitely learning to appreciate the difficulties of debugging multithreaded code. I'm working on a project that lacks good documentation, and I've spent close to 40 hours trying to debug this one issue, including 5 hours working with a person that is more knowledgeable on the project.

Comment: I'm trying to use AddressSanitizer right now, but I have to change all of the MakeFiles to use clang / clang++ instead of gcc and g++. Doing so is causing other issues too... Is there any way to debug this with gcc / g++?

Comment: @xur17 "change all of the Makefiles" -- that means you've written them incorrectly. You should use `CC` and `CXX` macros in your `Makefiles`. If you did, you'd just need to `make CC=clang CXX=clang++` and you'd be done. "causing other issues" -- Clang is more strict; your other issues probably need cleaning anyway (it may even expose the bug you are looking for). "Is there any way to debug with gcc" -- you'll have to use Valgrind, which doesn't require rebuilding your sources.

Comment: The makefiles are divided up into 4 or 5 separate makefiles for the whole project (I didn't set it up), but they are setup with CC and CXX macros as you said, so running `make CC=clang CXX=clang++` works. Unfortunately I am getting other errors once the program actually starts though (which could be pointing to other issues too I suppose). I'm giving Valgrind a try now.